# Is there a standard for parsing svg paths?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Svg path commands are encoded as strings by default

```
<path d="M1 144 C114 141 104 -0.5 250 1" />
```

Which makes it fairly hard to extract data from them / modify their data via js.

Say I want to move the first controlPoint to the right by 10, there is no simple way to get that information out of a string.

Instead, I want to represent the path commands in a better data structure, say an array or an object, something like this:

```
// "M1 144 C114 141 104 -0.5 250 1" as an array
const path = [
  {
    command: "M",
    points: {
      x: 1,
      y: 144,
    },
  },
  {
    command: "C",
    points: {
      x1: 114,
      y1: 141,
      x2: 104,
      y2: -0.5,
      x: 250,
      y: 1,
    },
  },
];
```

Before building my own parser / creating my own standard I wanted to check if there are any existing standards on how to do this. I figured browsers need to do this under the hood anyways so maybe there could be browser methods to do this?

Comment: See d3.js library. Depending on what you want to do, i might advise you further.

Comment: Are you looking for [W3C SVG standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/Overview.html)?

Comment: @Tarik d3 is just some syntactic sugar for dom manipulation no?

Comment: That and quite a bit of functionality to draw graphs, layouts, and a lot more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [standard](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData) for working with SVG path data has been defined by the SVG working group, but browser support is still lacking.

In the meantime, you can use a [polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill) to provide the `getPathData()` and `setPathData()` methods:

```js
const path = document.querySelector('path');
const data = path.getPathData();

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.3/path-data-polyfill.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M1 144 C114 141 104 -0.5 250 1" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! I see that this is already 5 years old, any reason why there is barely any documentation on this?

Comment: Browsers are notoriously slow to adopt new SVG features. They still mostly support only SVG 1.1, which is almost 10 years old. Not a priority I guess...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I think these days Chrome and Firefox support most of SVG 2.

Comment: SVG 1.1 had a interface [SVGPathSeg](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSeg) that was never implemented by browsers. It was [removed](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/changes.html#paths) for SVG 2. The [SVG Paths](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/) quoted above is only a draft so far, quote: "In the future, this specification will supercede the SVG 2 Paths chapter, however at this time the SVG 2 Paths chapter must be considered the normative definition for SVG Paths."

Comment: @ccprog `SVGPathSeg` was available at least in Chrome until version 47, and then it was removed. It was far more useful than the current API. Agree that the linked specification is only a working draft. Considering the SVG 2 Paths chapter as normative is fine, but it doesn't define an API for getting/setting structured path information. For that, the working draft is the closest thing we have to a standard.

Comment: @RobertLongson It's really a mixed bag. The [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_2_support_in_Mozilla) status is very patchy and for [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=225863) there are still a bunch of open issues. Some of these issues have caused me a fair bit of head scratching and ugly workarounds.